# Meteor: how to find record's position in the collection

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a cursor-based pagination and I need to find record's position in the collection by its _id. Is it possible to do so, using mongo query only (or several queries), and not fetching all the records and counting because that is  inefficient in case a collection contains millions of records as well as using createdBy field, because few records can be created at the same time.

The _ids are strings so I cannot just do something like

```
 n = myCollection.find({ _id: { $lte : 12345}}).count() ;
```

Comment: I don't think collections have a well-defined sort-order, so I think your question is ill-posed -- "record's position" is not defined. You will need to define a sort order by which you would like to define "position". Once you do that, I think you can actually see yourself how to change your query to do just what you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it in my code

Comment: @ChristianFritz I've check the Meteor docs and it says that when running `collection.find()` sorting applies by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Meteor `.find()` query sorts records in their natural order. This is not based on `_id`, but rather the position of the records [on disk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order).

Instead, you need to explicitly define the `sort` parameter if you want records to be sorted by `_id`.  Thus your query should look something like this:

```js
 // pageNo = the page number
 // pageSize = number of records per page

 records = myCollection.find({}, { 
    sort: { '_id' : 1 }, // Sort by _id in ascending order
    limit: pageSize // Only return pageSize elements
    skip: pageSize*pageNo // Skip the elements fetched on previous pages.
 });
```